# Dynamic queries and Dynamic Where clauses Solution

Tags: sql, dynamic, where-clause, sp-executesql

This week, I found myself in need of some dynamic queries. Now, dynamic queries and dynamic where clauses are nothing new and well documented all over the web.  Yet, I needed something more. I needed a fluid way of pulling new where fields to the client and allowing the users to make as many filters as needed. Even have multiple filters on a single field. Even more so, I needed to have access to all the possible operators within SQL server. The following is code is one way to make this happen. I will attempt to point out highlights of the code with the complete code at the bottom.

Hope you enjoy the code.

REQUIREMENTS

1. The solution will never allow SQL injections. (No exec(command) can be used)
2. The caller of the stored procedure could be anything.
3. The data set must come from a Stored Procedure.
4. Any field can be filtered as many times as needed, with just about any operation.
5. Any combination of filters should be allowed.
6. The stored procedure should allow for mandatory parameters

First, let us look over the parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyReport]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@p_iDistributorUID  INT,        --    manditory
@p_xParameters      XML = null  --optional parameters (hostile)
```

The first parameter must always be sent, in this demo we have a distributor id that must be sent in. The second parameter is an XML document. These are the “Dynamic Where Clauses” and we consider these potential sql injections, or as I perceive this parameter as hostile.

```
<root>
<OrFilters>
    <AndFilter Name="vcinvoicenumber" Operator="2" Value="inv12"/>
    <AndFilter Name="vcID" Operator="1" Value="asdqwe"/>
</OrFilters>
<OrFilters>
    <AndFilter Name="iSerialNumber" Operator="1" Value="123456"/>
</OrFilters>
```

NAME= field name(you could just use the object_id if you want to obfuscate) 
OPERATOR = SQL operators such as <,>,=,like,ect.
VALUE is what the users has entered.

Here is what the final code would look like.

```
Select *
FROM someTable
Where (
vcinvoicenumber like ‘inv12%’
and vcID = ‘asdqwe’
) 
Or
(
iSerialNumber   = ‘123456’  
)
```

First thing is to find out how many “OrFilters” tags there are.

```
SELECT @l_OrFilters = COUNT(1)
FROM   @p_xParameters.nodes('/root/OrFilters') Tab(Col)
```

Next we need a temp table to hold the values in the XML doc.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(keyid int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,value varchar(max))
```

We now create a cursor for the first “OrFilters”tag.

```
DECLARE OrFilter_cursor CURSOR LOCAL
FOR 
SELECT Tab.Col.value('@Name','varchar(max)') AS Name
    ,Tab.Col.value('@Operator','Smallint') AS Operator
    ,Tab.Col.value('@Value','varchar(max)') AS Value
    FROM   @p_xParameters.nodes('/root/OrFilters[sql:variable("@l_OrFilters")]/AndFilter') Tab(Col)
```

To make sure we have a valid field, we check against the system tables.

```
SELECT @l_ParameterInName = [all_columns].Name 
,@l_ParameterDataType= [systypes].Name
,@l_ParameterIsVariable= Variable
,@l_ParameterMax_length=max_length
,@l_ParameterpPrecision=precision
,@l_ParameterScale =[all_columns].scale
 FROM [AprDesktop].[sys].[all_views]
INNER JOIN [AprDesktop].[sys].[all_columns]
    ON [all_views].object_id = [all_columns].object_id
INNER JOIN [AprDesktop].[sys].[systypes]
    ON [all_columns].system_type_id = [systypes].xtype
WHERE [all_views].name = 'vw_CreditMemo_Lists'
and [all_columns].Name= @l_Name
```

Now we save the parameter to the temp table

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1   
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #temp (value) SELECT @l_Value
SET @l_FilterKey = @@IDENTITY
.
.   
.
```

We make a call to a function that will actually build the where clauses.

```
SET @l_TemporaryWhere +=  
dbo.sfunc_FilterWhereBuilder2(@l_Operator
,@l_ParameterInName
,@l_TemporaryWhere
,CAST(@l_FilterKey AS VARCHAR(10))
,@l_ParameterDataType
,@l_ParameterVariable)
```

Looking at this Function, you can see we used a case statement to genereate the where clause string.

```
set @l_CastToType = ' CAST( VALUE as ' + @p_DataType + @p_PrecisionScale + ') '
set @l_CastToString = ' CAST( '+@p_Field+' as VARCHAR(MAX)) '

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
SELECT @l_Return =    
    CASE 
--EQUAL
--ex: vcUID = (select  value FROM #temp where keyid = 1)
WHEN @p_Command = 1 
    THEN @p_Field + ' = (select  '+@l_CastToType+' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')' 

--BEGIN WITH
--ex:vcInvoiceNumber LIKE (select value+'%' FROM #temp where keyid = 2)
WHEN @p_Command = 2 
    THEN @l_CastToString +' LIKE (select value+'+ QUOTENAME('%','''') +' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'
.
.
.
```

And finally call the sp_execute.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @l_SqlCommand ,@l_Parameters, @p_iDistributorUID
```

CALLING CODE

```
DECLARE @return_value int

DECLARE @myDoc xml
SET @myDoc = 
'<root>
<OrFilters>
    <AndFilter Name="vcinvoicenumber" Operator="1" Value="123"/>
</OrFilters>

</root>'

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spp_CreditMemo_Request_List_v2]
    @p_siShowView = 1,
    @p_iDistributorUID = 3667,
    @p_xParameters = @myDoc

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

MAIN STORED PROCEDURE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @p_iDistributorUID          INT                 ,   --manditory
    @p_xParameters              XML         = null      --optional parameters(hostile)
AS
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @l_TemporaryWhere       NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- declare variables 
    DECLARE @l_SqlCommand           NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @l_Parameters           NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @l_WhereClause          NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE @l_OrFilters            INT

    --cursor variables
    DECLARE @l_Name                 VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @l_Operator             SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_Value                VARCHAR(MAX)

    --variables from the database views 
    DECLARE @l_ParameterInName      NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @l_ParameterDataType    NVARCHAR(128)
    DECLARE @l_ParameterIsVariable  BIT
    DECLARE @l_ParameterMax_length  SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_ParameterpPrecision  TINYINT
    DECLARE @l_ParameterScale       TINYINT

    --the variable that holds the latest @@identity
    DECLARE @l_FilterKey INT


    --init local variables
    SET @l_SqlCommand   =''
    SET @l_Parameters   =''
    SET @l_WhereClause  =''


    BEGIN TRY

        --verify manditory variables        
        if @p_iDistributorUID is null
            raiserror('Null values not allowed for @p_iDistributorUID', 16, 1)



        --Build the base query
        -- only the fields needed in the tile should be selected
        SET @l_SqlCommand = 
            ' SELECT * ' +
            ' FROM vw_Lists ' 



        --how many "OR" filters are there
        SELECT @l_OrFilters = COUNT(1)
        FROM   @p_xParameters.nodes('/root/OrFilters') Tab(Col)


        --create a temp table to 
        --hold the parameters to send into the sp
        CREATE TABLE #temp
        (
            keyid int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,value varchar(max)
        )


        --Cycle through all the "OR" Filters
        WHILE @l_OrFilters > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @l_TemporaryWhere = '';

            --Create a cursor of the Next "OR" filter
            DECLARE OrFilter_cursor CURSOR LOCAL
            FOR 
                SELECT Tab.Col.value('@Name','varchar(max)') AS Name
                    ,Tab.Col.value('@Operator','Smallint') AS Operator
                    ,Tab.Col.value('@Value','varchar(max)') AS Value
                FROM   @p_xParameters.nodes('/root/OrFilters[sql:variable("@l_OrFilters")]/AndFilter') Tab(Col)

            OPEN OrFilter_cursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM OrFilter_cursor 
            INTO @l_Name, @l_Operator,@l_Value  

            WHILE    @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN

                --verify the parameter actual exists
                --  and get parameter details
                SELECT @l_ParameterInName = [all_columns].Name 
                    ,@l_ParameterDataType= [systypes].Name
                    ,@l_ParameterIsVariable= Variable
                    ,@l_ParameterMax_length=max_length
                    ,@l_ParameterpPrecision=precision
                    ,@l_ParameterScale =[all_columns].scale
                FROM [AprDesktop].[sys].[all_views]
                    INNER JOIN [sys].[all_columns]
                        ON [all_views].object_id = [all_columns].object_id
                    INNER JOIN [sys].[systypes]
                        ON [all_columns].system_type_id = [systypes].xtype
                WHERE [all_views].name = 'vw_CreditMemo_Lists'
                    and [all_columns].Name= @l_Name

                --if the paremeter exists, create a where clause
                --  if the parameters does not exists, possible injection
                IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1   
                BEGIN

                    --insert into the temp table the parameter value
                    --NOTE: we have turned in the @@identity as the key
                    INSERT INTO #temp (value) SELECT @l_Value
                    SET @l_FilterKey = @@IDENTITY


                    -- if the parameter is variable in length, add the length
                    DECLARE @l_ParameterVariable VARCHAR(1000)
                    IF @l_ParameterIsVariable = 1
                    BEGIN
                        SET @l_ParameterVariable ='(' + CAST(@l_ParameterMax_length as VARCHAR(MAX))  + ') '
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @l_ParameterVariable = ''
                    END

                    -- create the where clause for this filter
                    SET @l_TemporaryWhere +=  
                        dbo.sfunc_FilterWhereBuilder2(@l_Operator
                                                     ,@l_ParameterInName
                                                     ,@l_TemporaryWhere
                                                     ,CAST(@l_FilterKey AS VARCHAR(10))
                                                     ,@l_ParameterDataType
                                                     ,@l_ParameterVariable)


                END

                FETCH NEXT FROM OrFilter_cursor 
                INTO @l_Name, @l_Operator,@l_Value  

            END

            -- clean up the cursor
            CLOSE OrFilter_cursor
            DEALLOCATE OrFilter_cursor

            --add the and filers
            IF @l_TemporaryWhere != ''
            BEGIN

                --if the where clause is not empty, we need to add an OR
                IF @l_WhereClause != ''
                BEGIN
                    SET @l_WhereClause += ' or ';
                END

                --add temp to where clause including the 
                SET @l_WhereClause += '(' + @l_TemporaryWhere + ')';

            END

            --get the next AND set
            SET @l_OrFilters = @l_OrFilters - 1

        END

        --generate the where clause
        IF @l_WhereClause != ''
        BEGIN
            SET @l_WhereClause ='('+ @l_WhereClause + ') AND '
        END

        --add in the first mandatory parameter          
        SET @l_WhereClause  += '  vw_CreditMemo_Lists.iDistributorUID = @l_iDistributorUID ' 
        SET @l_Parameters   += '@l_iDistributorUID int'


        --do we need to attach the where clause
        if @l_WhereClause IS NOT NULL AND RTRIM(LTRIM(@l_WhereClause)) != ''
        BEGIN
            SET @l_SqlCommand += ' WHERE '+ @l_WhereClause;
        END


        print @l_SqlCommand

        --query for the data
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @l_SqlCommand ,@l_Parameters, @p_iDistributorUID

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @ErrorUID int;
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT 
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();


        --write the to stored procedure log 
        EXEC @ErrorUID = spp_Errors_CreateEntry @l_SqlCommand 


        -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
        -- information about the original error that caused
        -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
        RAISERROR (@ErrorUID, -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState -- State.
                   );


        IF(CURSOR_STATUS('LOCAL','OrFilter_cursor') >= 0)
        BEGIN
            CLOSE OrFilter_cursor
        END     

        IF(CURSOR_STATUS('LOCAL','OrFilter_cursor') = -1)
        BEGIN
            DEALLOCATE OrFilter_cursor
        END     


    END CATCH

    return

END
```

FUNCTION

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[sfunc_FilterWhereBuilder2]
(
    @p_Command          SMALLINT                ,
    @p_Field            VARCHAR(1000)           ,
    @p_WhereClause      VARCHAR(MAX)            ,
    @p_KeyValue         VARCHAR(10)             ,
    @p_DataType         VARCHAR(100)    = NULL  ,
    @p_PrecisionScale   VARCHAR(100)    = NULL

)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @l_Return       VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @l_CastToType   VARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @l_CastToString VARCHAR(MAX)

    set @l_CastToType = ' CAST( VALUE as ' + @p_DataType + @p_PrecisionScale + ') '
    set @l_CastToString = ' CAST( '+@p_Field+' as VARCHAR(MAX)) '

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @l_Return =    
        CASE 
            --EQUAL
            --ex: vcBurnUID = (select  value FROM #temp where keyid = 1)
            WHEN @p_Command = 1 
                THEN @p_Field + ' = (select  '+@l_CastToType+' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')' 

            --BEGIN WITH
            --ex:vcInvoiceNumber LIKE (select value+'%' FROM #temp where keyid = 2)
            WHEN @p_Command = 2 
                THEN @l_CastToString +' LIKE (select value+'+ QUOTENAME('%','''') +' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --END WITH
            --ex:vcInvoiceNumber LIKE (select '%'+value FROM #temp where keyid = 2)
            WHEN @p_Command = 4 
                THEN @l_CastToString +' LIKE (select '+ QUOTENAME('%','''') +'+value FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --END WITH
            --ex:vcInvoiceNumber LIKE (select '%'+value+'%' FROM #temp where keyid = 2)
            WHEN @p_Command = 8 
                THEN @l_CastToString +' LIKE (select '+ QUOTENAME('%','''') +'+value+'+ QUOTENAME('%','''') +' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --greater than
            --ex: iSerialNumber > (select  CAST(value as INT) FROM #temp where keyid = 1)
            WHEN @p_Command = 16 
                THEN @p_Field +' > (select  '+@l_CastToType+' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --greater than equal
            --ex: iSerialNumber >= (select  CAST(value as INT) FROM #temp where keyid = 1)
            WHEN @p_Command = 32 
                THEN @p_Field +' >= (select  '+@l_CastToType+' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --Less than
            --ex: iSerialNumber < (select  CAST(value as INT) FROM #temp where keyid = 1)
            WHEN @p_Command = 64 
                THEN @p_Field +' < (select  '+@l_CastToType+' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --less than equal
            --ex: iSerialNumber <= (select  CAST(value as INT) FROM #temp where keyid = 1)
            WHEN @p_Command = 128 
                THEN @p_Field +' <= (select  '+@l_CastToType+' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --less than equal
            --ex: iSerialNumber != (select  CAST(value as INT) FROM #temp where keyid = 1)
            WHEN @p_Command = 256 
                THEN @p_Field +' != (select  '+@l_CastToType+' FROM #temp where keyid = ' + @p_KeyValue + ')'

            --default to an empty string
            ELSE ''

        END 

        if @l_Return != '' and LEN(@p_WhereClause) > 1
        begin
            set @l_Return =  ' AND ' + @l_Return
        end

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @l_Return

END
```